# Unity Player Collider does not work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I have not worked with unity in a while so I am a little rusty.

I have:

- Game Object with a mesh Collider which is my ground
- A Empty Game Object with a Character Controller Which holds my player game objects

My Empty Game Object that holds a player doesnt not stand on top of the ground.

So half my player is going through the ground but the Empty Game Object stays ontop of the ground which holds my character.

[image: My Player In game]

[image: Player set up]

[image: player settings]

Comment: Have you changed there layers and not updated the Physics to say which layers can interact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible problem with pivot of 3d model(Character)

With your current heirarchy structure: One possible solution is to make Center:y = -1.8 in the character controller component.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I had to go in my charactersetup script and transform all y positions by the height of character thank you